# Can't get plain text google maps api html_instructions in php

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I'm trying my best to get plain text from google maps directions api where it says html_instructions in json. everything is encoded in html and i want to output plain text.

here is what I'm getting 
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWwAo.png)

this is what i want : [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lXY1.png)

I tried ay type of preg_replace, it couldn't help me out.

**Google maps api link**
[Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sandnes&destination=vigrestad&key=)

Comment: Can you show how you are invoking the API? How you are asking for directions?

Comment: i added the link of api.

Comment: If you are an experienced Javascript programmer you can use the DirectionsService and DirectionsRenderer objects to either draw the directions on a map or display the directions in English text (or whatever language). The example at <https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-complex> shows how to display in text. One sneaky way to get at the text is then to read it from the HTML generated by DirectionsRenderer. This might be easier than trying to parse the JSON yourself.

Comment: Thx, but i think u did not get my question. Have you seen those images i posted above?

Comment: Yes I did, but I thought it would be easier to let Google objects parse for you. I believe we can do what you ask using preg_replace() so I will test and post an answer shortly...

Comment: Ok see reply below. If it is what you need you may consider accepting the answer by clicking on the "tick' below the upvote/downvote arrows to the left of the answer :-). If not ask for more clarification...

Comment: One final simpler version, after some thought and testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Previous code snippet removed and replaced by workable small program.

Note that when you process the data with json_decode() the unicode segments like `\u003cb\u003eFlintergata\u003c/b\u003e` are converted to `<b>Flintergata</b>`. This helps a lot to make the Regex more readable.

Note the `$details` array is a multilevel associative array, so you need to dig down as shown to find the data you need.

Note also the URL you provided results in 1  route, with 1 leg. So the code I provided shows and processes the first leg of the first route.

If you use a different URL you may get multiple routes each with multiple steps. The code will still process the first leg of the first route, but its each (with outer loops) to show all of them (not shown below).

The explanation of the regex string '"~>([A-Z].*?)<~"' is as follows.

The `'#'` at each side are the PHP delimiters - but you can use other chars also and would not make any difference.

The `<b>` and `</b>` are saying that each matched string must start with `<b>` and end with `</b>`.

Inside the `(  )` a "capture group" that says we want to extract that part of the string only (excluding the `<b>` and `</b>`).

`[A-Z]` says begin with a capital letter

`.*` says follow with 0 or more of any character.

The `?` makes the * non_greedy so this case, stop current match when it meets the next `<`.

The list of matches for each string goes into an array called `$matches` and `$matches[1]` is an array of capture group matches ( ie text within the `<b>` and `</b>` is removed).

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sandnes&destination=vigrestad&key="); 
$details = json_decode($json,true);

// $details is a large associative array   
// print all the instructions for the first step of the fist leg of the first route
echo PHP_EOL."Here are the unfiltered html instructions for first leg of first route ".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
$steps = $details['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'];
foreach($steps as $step){
    echo($step['html_instructions']).PHP_EOL;  // print to see format
    // we see unicode html_entities have been replaced and now look like <b>  </b> etc
}

// now extra the required information from each step
echo PHP_EOL."Here are the filtered html instructions for first leg of first route ".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($steps as $step)
{ 
    //preg_match_all("~003e([A-Z].*?)\\\\u003c~", $step['html_instructions'], $match); // not needed now
    preg_match_all('#,<b>([A-Z].*?)</b>#, $step['html_instructions'], $match);  // now detects strings between '>' and '<'
    foreach($match[1] as $instructionPart)
    { 
        echo $instructionPart." "; 
    } 
    echo PHP_EOL; 

} 
?>
```

Comment: This is closer?

Comment: I'm sorry for late response. Thanks for your work anyway. But i thought that would work for me. The code you wrote above. not giving me any effect by using file_get_contents from json and use ur code. could you please rewrite with complete code.

Comment: **i tried this**

`<?php

$json = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sandnes&destination=vigrestad&key=");
$details = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($details as $strn){
    preg_match_all("~003e([A-Z].*?)\\\\u003c~", $strn, $match);
    foreach($match[1] as $name){
     echo $name." ";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
} 
?>`

Comment: Ok thank you for sending code you have tried. See new reply . If you need more help or explanation, I suggest make a new question and send me a comment so I can address it. Best to close this off now I think.

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out. I think I found out a better solutions by changing the json to xml and get content from there. as u can see my code here:

`<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars_decode("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=sandnes&destination= vigrestad&key=");
$content = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('#&lt;b&gt;(.*?)&lt;/b&gt;#m', $content, $matches_title);
$title = $matches_title[1];

$title = str_replace(array("left", "right", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"), '', $title);
echo implode("<center><br>", $title);
?>`

Comment: OK great. Both solutions are pretty much the same thing. People work more with JSON these days rather than XML for this type of data download, but whatever works!  Good luck..